# WSO2 Proxy service doesn't return expected result when used in Postman client

Tags: proxy, wso2, postman, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service which returns records from a database and sends the records to an endpoint. All this in a single Proxy service. It works fine when I use the Try this service in the WSO2 UI itself. But when I use the same URL in postman or any other Client, the result is a success but doesn't return any records nor posts these records to the endpoint. 
Any idea what would I be doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: When you get the successful response back what are your response headers?  Also have you tried turning up logging, setting org.apache.http.headers and org.apache.http.wire to TRACE to track your transaction?

Comment: I am debugging more, The first endpoint where I am getting the records from the database is itself not returning records. However it returns records when i use the "Try the service".                                                                         Response header                                                                          
Content-Type →application/xml; charset=UTF-8                                   Transfer-Encoding →chunked

Comment: Are those response headers from "Try the service" or from your Postman transaction?  Are you able to include the full response (Response code, headers and Body) from the postman transaction?

Comment: Response from "Try the service "  :                                             
 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
"Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"

Response from Postman                                                          
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Type →application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding →chunked                                                                  Both are successful but In postman, I am not getting the data.

Comment: lets forget "Try the service" for the moment....
I do not see your response code from postman transaction?

Comment: use tcpmon and post the request/response in each case, with tryit and with postman.

Comment: I am able to get the output now. The thing which was missing was I had to mention the Content-Type : application/xml in the header in the PostMan. The data service returned records. Silly that now i think about.

Comment: Thank you so much @jchaplin